# Centos yum install git-svn

Tags: centos, yum

Running yum install on Centos

```
   yum install git-svn
```

is producing the following errors:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.eshk.hk
 * base: centos.01link.hk
 * epel: mirror.bjtu.edu.cn
 * extras: mirror.eshk.hk
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * updates: mirror.vpshosting.com.hk
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git-svn.i386 0:1.7.3.4-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) for package: git-svn
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git-svn
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: git-svn
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17010-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package perl-TermReadKey.i386 0:2.30-4.el5 set to be updated
---> Package subversion-perl.i386 0:1.4.2-4.el5_3.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: subversion = 1.4.2-4.el5_3.1 for package: subversion-perl
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
subversion-perl-1.4.2-4.el5_3.1.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: subversion = 1.4.2-4.el5_3.1 is needed by package subversion-perl-1.4.2-4.el5_3.1.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: subversion = 1.4.2-4.el5_3.1 is needed by package subversion-perl-1.4.2-4.el5_3.1.i386 (base)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Comment: Is `subversion` installed? `rpm -q subversion`

Comment: yes, subversion is installed on base

Comment: running code returns:  subversion-1.6.13-0.1.el5.rf

Comment: @Community, RHEL5? really?) it's EOL, EOS years ago)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like so-called repository hell. The problem is that subversion from RPMForge does not satisfy subversion-perl from base repo which is going to be installed as a dependency. You should remove subversion which is installed from RPMForge repo, then temporary disable the RPMForge repo, then install subversion and subversion-perl from base. You can enable RPMForge back after that and install svn-git.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an easy fix.. try this

`rpm -ivh ftp://ftp.icm.edu.pl/vol/rzm1/linux-centos/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/subversion-1.4.2-4.el5_3.1.i386.rpm`

Then try your yum command